# Github latest release button capability

Tags: github

I've found out that in github you can use a Latest Release button or link to always clone the latest tag from that project without specifically specifying the version number, however if I use something like this: (links are just examples project is private)

https://github.com/company/project1/releases/latest  (this is how I've learned the latest release link should be accessed)

it just redirects me back to:

https://github.com/company/project1/releases/

My guess is that I have to enable the Latest Release button/tag somehow? How will I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works only if your release has an artificat associated to it.

See for instance: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases/latest

[image: artifact]

If you define releases without ever attaching a binary to any of them, then 'latest' redirects you to the `releases` page of your project indeed.

Comment: is it possible to have a link to always release the latest tag from a project without having a binary release attached? The reason I'm asking is because I have some chef scripts that automatically release a project from github and currently I still have to manually update them with the latest tag to make sure that the latest one is released