# Link to download latest version tag of a repository from GitHub

Tags: github, github-api

I want to make download link for latest version of my application from GitHub tags. But I can not use GitHub releases, only just tags to make the new version. So I want an universal link to the latest **tag** zipball. I already did that with jQuery and GitHub API, but I also need a non JS fallback. Is there any option how to do it?

**Edit**:
I've found some possibilities, but none of them is accurate for my problem:

- https://github.com/:user/:repo/releases just points to the latest release, not tag, and doesn't start downloading.
- https://github.com/:user/:repo/archive/master.zip just downloads master, not the latest tagged version.
- https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/zipball/master does exactly the same as the one above.

**Edit 2**: Is there also any option to download latest **release** directly? It could help to find out the same for tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find out a way to easily do want you want, however I ended up making sure there is a tag for latest so then you link such as

https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/zipball/latest

It sounds like you have control of tags so that should do the trick for now for the static link fallback.

Comment: https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow/releases/tag/r66-oriental-skylark works for this particular repo and redirects to https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/releases/tag/v1.4.11

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827437/github-latest-release-button-capability    You need attached artifacts for that button to show and the latest link to work correctly.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I could add a tag called latest to the newest version tag. Then it should work. That sounds as a really good idea. I'll try to do it that way. Unfortunately I haven't any artifacts I could attach.